# Eigenvalue of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In class today, we defined a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$ s.t. $T(w, z) = (-z, w)$.

By definition $\lambda(w,z) = (-z, w)$.

$\lambda w = -z$

$\lambda z = w$

so $\lambda^2 z = -z$ so $\lambda = \pm i$.

To find an eigenvector for $i$, we do:

$i(w, z) = (-z, w)$

$iw = -z$

$iz = w$

so we get $i(iz) = -z$ so $-z = -z$. Additionally, we can also derive that $w = w$.

My professor suggested that the correct eigenvector is $(z, zi)$. How do we get to that? Specifically, how do we derive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's work was only a couple of steps short of the solution. Below is a step-by-step breakdown.

> To find an eigenvector for $i$, we do:
>
> $i(w, z) = (-z, w)$

The equality is just $\,T(w,z) = \lambda (w,z)\,$ where $\,T(w,z)=(-z,w)\,$ and $\,\lambda = i\,$.

> $iw = -z$
>
> $iz = w$
>
> so we get $i(iz) = -z$ so $-z = -z$.

What this means is that $\,z\,$ is unconstrained i.e. it can be chosen to be any complex value  **(1)**.

> Additionally, we can also derive that $w = w$.

Once a value for $\,z\,$ is chosen, however, its corresponding $\,w\,$ must be determined from one of the two equations for the eigenvalue, for example the second one directly gives $\,w = iz\,$  **(2)**.

> My professor suggested that the correct eigenvector is $(z, zi)$. How do we get to that? Specifically, how do we derive it?

It follows from the above that for any $\,z\,$  **(1)**  and $\,w = iz\,$  **(2)**  the vector $\,(w,z) = (iz,z)\,$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\,\lambda = i\,$. The value $\,z = 0\,$ must be excluded, though, because it results in $\,(w,z)=(0,0)\,$, but an eigenvector cannot be the zero vector [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Formal_definition).

With the substitution $\,z \mapsto -iz\,$ the eigenvector $\,(w,z) \mapsto (z, -iz)\,$, which is an equally correct answer. However, professor's suggestion $\,(z, iz)\,$ are eigenvectors corresponding to the other eigenvalue $\,\lambda = - i\,$, instead.

Comment: Could you explain step (2), where the corresponding w must be chosen from one of the two equations? I understand you get $(iz, z)$, $z(i,1)$, but I don't understand why parametrization works.

Comment: I get its saying something about the span, but I don't fully understand the derivation of it.

Comment: @user129393192 You have the two equations $iw=-z$ and $iz=w$. If you multiply the first one by $i$ you get $-w=-iz \iff w=iz$. This shows that the two equations are in fact equivalent, and equivalent to $w = iz$, so solving either one for $w$ gives the $w$ for a given $z$, which is $w=iz$.

Comment: Right. So we end up with $(iz, z)$, which we make $z(i,1)$ by pulling $z$ out. I was asking about this implication of the parametrization.

Comment: @user129393192 One linear equation with two variables will always have a line as the (infinite) solution set, from which the origin must be removed because of the definition of an eigenvector. This is expected, because if $\mathrm{v}$ is an eigenvector, then any non-zero scalar multiple of $\mathrm{v}$ is also an eigenvector.

Comment: Got it, so really the $span{(i,1)}$ (except 0, so it is not a subspace) are the eigenvectors, the $z$ pulled out reflects this, and $z \ne 0$

Answer (score 0):

You can see that $\lambda(z,zi)=(-zi,z)=-i(z,zi)$, so $(z,zi)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $i$.

Comment: Would $(iz, z)$ also be one? Since $i(iz, z) = (-z, iz)$?

Comment: "*is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $i$*" $\;-\;$ What you wrote proves it's with eigenvalue $\,-i\,$, instead.